# Prevent Entityform Duplicate Submissions

Tags: forms, entities

I have a simple text entityform setup on my drupal website. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent users from submitting a submission that has already been submitted. I am new to using Rules, but my guess would be there is a way to do so using that.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "submission that has already been submitted"? Double clicking the submit button or submissions with the same data?

Comment: Adding a submission with the same data.

Comment: It depends on how complex your forms are. You can use Views and Rules to query previous submissions to see if there is a matching one. You would have to use contextual filters and VBO/Rules. But the would probably only work with simple forms not ones using textarea, multiple value fields, or file uploads.

If you have a form with just selects and checkboxes I think that would be doable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Hide Submit](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit) moddule:

> Some users accidentally click the submit button more than once while
>   waiting for their post to be saved. In some cases this may result
>   duplicate postings or duplicate e-commerce orders.
>
> There are few ideas on how to solve duplicate postings but none is
>   perfect. One of the solutions is a bit of jQuery to hide or disable
>   the submit button after it has been clicked and replace it with an
>   informative text such as "Processing..." .
>
> This module wraps that jQuery code and provides some options. Of
>   course this, too, is not a perfect solution as it requires Javascript
>   to be enabled. For browsers with Javascript disabled this module will
>   have no effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you'd like to avoid form submissions with similar data (which really means a combination of fields that are unique), I think the best option would be the [Entity Unique](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_unique) module.